# AngularCLI : Invalid build target. Only 'development' and 'production' are available

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to add a local environment configuration file to generate the build.

```
            "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
            "environments": {
             "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
             "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
             "local": "environments/environment.local.ts",
             "staging": "environments/environment.staging.ts"
        }
```

But it is saying "**Invalid build target. Only 'development' and 'production' are available.**
"
I am on the following angular environment:

Angular CLI: 1.6.0
Node: 9.2.0

OS: linux x64

Angular: 5.1.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.0

@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.35

@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22

@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.41

@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0

@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.0

@schematics/angular: 0.1.10

@schematics/schematics: 0.0.10

typescript: 2.4.0

webpack: 3.10.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the environment with the --environment flag. What you probably tried is changing the target (--target), which is different and only works for production and development

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build