# why do I get Invalid target runtime error

Tags: angular

I am trying to run an angular project and getting this error.

​An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid target: {"project":"firstAngularApp","target":"build","configuration":"development"}

Comment: There isnt enough information available here to reliably pinpoint the error you are seeing but perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749466/angularcli-invalid-build-target-only-development-and-production-are-avail) can help?

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? One of Angular apps is doing exactly the same thing, and I've not changed my code.

Comment: @MichaelCockinos sorry, I don't remember but maybe check the node version?

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded to 14. Fixed it by creating another Angular app using 13.2.2 and moved my files across. Downgrading was going to prove unreliable and time consuming

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, but I finally solved it. In my case, the reason was that I mistakenly modified the <projects -> MyProjectName> in the angular.json file when I upgrading the Angular version. After I restored the previous project name, my project worked normally.